.env variables are not being loaded/read correctly
Our project is a React and TypeScript project made with React App Rewired first, but migrated to Vite now.
I have been working on getting Jest to work (after trying to use Vitest, where I ran into completely different issues). The issue I'm having now is that it's giving me this error message:
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VITE_HOST')

Where VITE_HOST is defined in our .test.env file as follows:
VITE_HOST="http://localhost:3000"

The script I'm running is as follows:
    "test": "dotenv -e ./src/environments/.env.test jest --testResultsProcessor --detectOpenHandles --bail",


I already tested by doing this if the .env file is even being loaded:
dotenv -e ./src/environments/.env.test node -e
// Followed by:
 console.log(process.env)

Which actually logged all the environment variables correctly.
My jest.config.js looks like this:
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} **/
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.m?[tj]sx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        moduleNameMapper: {
          '\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
          '\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg|png)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
          '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect':
            '@testing-library/jest-dom',
        },
        transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!variables/.*)'],
        useESM: true,
        babelConfig: true,
        diagnostics: {
          ignoreCodes: [1343],
        },
        astTransformers: {
          before: [
            {
              path: 'node_modules/ts-jest-mock-import-meta',
              options: {
                metaObjectReplacement: { url: 'https://www.url.com' },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  setupFiles: ['dotenv/config'],
  maxWorkers: 1,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect': '@testing-library/jest-dom',
  },
};


To get the environment variables, we have a function that does the following:
export const getProcessEnv = (key: string): ProcessEnv =>
  new ProcessEnv(key, import.meta.env[key]);

export class ProcessEnv {
  constructor(public name: string, public rawValue: string | undefined) {}


Which is then used in our environment.ts file as follows:
import { getProcessEnv } from '../utils/environmentValidator';

const allowedEnvironmentTypes = [
  'local',
  'staging',
  'production',
  'test',
] as const;

export const ENV = {
  HOST: getProcessEnv('VITE_HOST').asString(''),

After which we use the environment variables from the exported ENV const. However, even just doing import.meta.env.VITE_HOST doesn't work. It also returns "undefined", apparently, when it shouldn't.

What do you have in place to take VITE_-prefixed env vars and expose them on import.meta.env? That's handled by Vite usually, which Vitest will also use, but you don't show anything to do that for Jest. You're using ts-jest-mock-import-meta, but only for import.meta.url.

@jonrsharpe I don't believe I have anything in place for that. Didn't even know that was needed, to be honest. How would I go about learning more about that? Do you have a suggestion on what to do here?
